# Remove value/item from a list but leave index intact

Tags: python-2.7

Can anyone tell me how to remove an item from a Python2.7/Django1.6.2 list while leaving the index intact?

I want to be able to cycle through a list multiple times and remove the items using the original index. I think what I'm trying to achieve below is fairly common but I don't know the name for it.

Or perhaps a better way to solve the below?

**Origional List**

```
images = ['A.jpg', 'B.jpg', 'C.jpg', 'D.jpg', 'E.jpg']
```

The index for the above would be `0, 1, 2, 3, 4`

If I use e.g. `images.pop(2)` it appears to remove both the index and the value. This causes a problem when cycling through the list multiple times to remove different items as the original declared index and values do not match.

```
class SurveyWizardOne(SessionWizardView):    

def get_context_data(self, form, **kwargs):
    context = super(SurveyWizardOne, self).get_context_data(form, **kwargs)                 
    if self.steps.current == '5':
        display_image = random.choice(images)                     
        context.update({'display_image': display_image})                                          
        if display_image == 'A.jpg':
            images.pop(0)  
        elif display_image == 'B.jpg':
            images.pop(1)
        elif display_image == 'C.jpg':
            images.pop(2)
        elif display_image == 'D.jpg':
            images.pop(3)
        elif display_image == 'E.jpg':
            images.pop(4)
```

So in the above scenario if `display_image` is `C.jpg` it gets 'poped' from the list using `images.pop(2)`

**Updated List**

```
images = ['A.jpg', 'B.jpg', 'D.jpg', 'E.jpg']
```

The index for the above would now be `0, 1, 2, 3` (I think)

```
    if self.steps.current == '6':
        display_image = random.choice(images)                     
        context.update({'display_image': display_image})                                          
        if display_image == 'A.jpg':
            images.pop(0)  
        elif display_image == 'B.jpg':
            images.pop(1)
        elif display_image == 'C.jpg':
            images.pop(2)
        elif display_image == 'D.jpg':
            images.pop(3)
        elif display_image == 'E.jpg':
            images.pop(4)
```

However if the second time cycling through the list `display_image` is `D.jpg` I should be using `images.pop(2)` but my solution is `images.pop(3)`

The solution that I can think of to this issue is some way to remove the value from the list, so it cant be selected again but to keep the index intact so that I can continue cycling through it and remove each in turn. Can anyone tell me how this might be done?

Thanks ;-)

Comment: What should happen once you've used all five images? Do you want to go through again? In the same order, or a difference one? There are many better ways to do this (hard-coding the indices is a bad move), but the approach will depend on your aims.

Comment: When they have gone through all 5 images they simple move onto the next page of the SessionWizardView (used for splitting a form over multiple pages) which is a multiple choice question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The minimal change would be to `remove` (which takes the value), rather than `pop` (which takes the index):

```
if self.steps.current == '6':
    display_image = random.choice(images)                     
    context.update({'display_image': display_image}) 
    images.remove(display_image)
```

This way you don't have to hard-code the locations within the list. Alternatively, randomly pick the index:

```
if self.steps.current == '6':
    index = random.randrange(len(images))
    display_image = images.pop(index)                     
    context.update({'display_image': display_image})
```

Comment: First solution worked a charm. My code is quite verbose but I hope to put some on CodeReview later to look for improvements. Thanks for the solution, very elegant